# The method sendKeys(CharSequence[]) in the type WebElement is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, sendkeys

I am trying to send a String to the sendkeys() method, but it is not accepting and throwing an error as

my codes follows:

```
package healthcare;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven.WebDriverBackedSelenium;

public class MailRegister_Webdriver {
    public WebDriver driver;
    public Selenium selenium;
    public void openURL(){
//System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\Library\\chromedriver.exe");       
driver=new FirefoxDriver();
selenium=new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, "http://mail.in.com");
driver.get("http://mail.in.com");
    }
    public void register() throws Exception{
//driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.registernow")).click();
selenium.click("css=input.registernow");
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.id("fname")).sendKeys("Nagesh");
selenium.select("day", "10");
selenium.select("month", "Jun");
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("year"))).selectByVisibleText("1999");
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@name='radiousername'])[5]")).click();    
Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("nag123");
        driver.findElement(By.id("repassword")).sendKeys);
        driver.findElement(By.id("altemail")).sendKeys();
        driver.findElement(By.id("mobileno")).sendKeys("7894561230");
        driver.findElement(By.id("imageField")).click();
}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MailRegister_Webdriver m=new MailRegister_Webdriver();
        m.openURL();
        m.register();
    }
}
```

Can somebody help on this, Why Sendkeys() method is not taking String values as arguments?

Comment: Can you let us know @ which line you are facing issue?

Comment: It would be great to have stacktrace (or name of exception) and probably snippet of HTML.

Comment: driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("nag123");

Comment: a red color underline is showing for sendkeys text, and if we analyse the error, The method sendKeys(CharSequence[]) in the type WebElement is not applicable for the arguments (String) is displaying

Comment: Can you please clarify two next strings         `driver.findElement(By.id("repassword")).sendKeys);` -- sendKeys without argument and extra bracket
`driver.findElement(By.id("altemail")).sendKeys();`  -- you use sendKeys without argument, I'm not sure it is valid use.

Comment: Aren't you missing a bracket in `driver.findElement(By.id("repassword")).sendKeys);`?

Comment: driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("nag123"); I am asking about this line

Comment: What IDE did you use? Eclipse or IntelliJIDEA?

Comment: What IDE are you using? Eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA or NetBeans?

Answer (score 34):

It has a simple solution. Change your compiler compliance level from 1.4 to 1.7.

Follow these steps in your eclipse:

1. Right click on your java project and select **Build Path** -> Click on
   **Configure Build Path...**
2. In project properties window, Click/select **Java Compiler** at the left
   panel
3. At the right panel, change the Compiler compliance level from 1.4 to 1.7
   (Select which is higher version in your eclipse)
4. Lastly Click on **Apply** and **OK**

Now check your code. it will never show the same error.

Comment: In JDK Compliance panel: the combo containing 1.4 is showing disabled in my case. So I could not change it to 1.7 or higher version from 1.4

Comment: u have to enable the project specification  settings , which is available on java compiler window on top.. then you can change the versions,

Answer (score 3):

```
element.sendKeys(new String[]{"Hello, selenium"});
```

My code looks like this, it's working.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible solution for this

1- Change the compiler version from old version to 1.5 or greater.

2- Change the JRE version from JRE8 to JRE7.

I have created a detailed article on this may be it will help.

http://learn-automation.com/solution-for-sendkeyscharsequence-in-selenium/

Answer (score 0):

Try to click into the WebElement before you sending keys to it:

```
public static void login(WebDriver driver, String userName, String password) {
    driver.get("loginPage.html");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(userName);
    Thread.sleep(TestConfiguration.time);
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(password);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
}
```

You should use clear() method to clear the input field before using sendKeys().

Comment: There is no text previously in the edit box, and the error is coming while writing the code itself

Answer (score 0):

You can try by replacing your following lines of code:

```
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("nag123");
        driver.findElement(By.id("repassword")).sendKeys);
        driver.findElement(By.id("altemail")).sendKeys();
        driver.findElement(By.id("mobileno")).sendKeys("7894561230");
        driver.findElement(By.id("imageField")).click();
```

to

```
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("nag123");
        driver.findElement(By.id("repassword")).sendKeys("");
        driver.findElement(By.id("altemail")).sendKeys("");
        driver.findElement(By.id("mobileno")).sendKeys("7894561230");
        driver.findElement(By.id("imageField")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of java you need to either convert the primitive (i.e. Char) to String (look here: http://tech.deepumohan.com/2013/03/java-how-to-convert-primitive-char-to.html)

Or switch to a java version that would do it for you (see here: http://java-performance.info/changes-to-string-java-1-7-0_06/)

Answer (score -1):

Set the JRE System Library again. If you use eclipse follow the steps below:

1. Go to project properties
2. Select **Java Build Path** at the left panel -> Select **Libraries** tab at the right
3. Click/select JRE System Library[] -> Click **Edit** button at the right side
4. Set your preferred JRE and click **Finish** button
5. Lastly click **OK** button from the project properties pop up window

Instead of editing you can also do by deleting and adding. The steps are:

1. Right-click on project » Properties » Java Build Path
2. Select Libraries tab
3. Find the JRE System Library and remove it
4. Click Add Library... button at right side » Add the JRE System Library 
   (Workspace default JRE)